# Magento2 How to get customer group name by using group id?

Tags: magento2, customer, template, customer-group

How can I get customer group name by using group id in a template (`phtml` file) ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If  you have group id then add below code at your block class

```
protected $groupRepository;
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Customer\Api\GroupRepositoryInterface $groupRepository,
    ...
) {
    $this->groupRepository = $groupRepository;
}

public function getGroupName($groupId){
    $group = $this->groupRepository->getById($groupId);
    echo $group->getCode();
}
```

At last in phtml file you will get  group name by:

```
$block->getGroupName($groupId)
```

If you want to *get group name by group id at phtml using Object manager* and donot want edit block class then  you can use below code at `phtml`

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$groupRepository  = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Customer\Api\GroupRepositoryInterface');
$group = $groupRepository->getById([GroupId]);
var_dump($group->getData());
echo $group->getCode();
```

***But direct use of  Object manager is not good idea***,So best  idea to add code at block class.

Comment: You were 1 minute faster, but I'll leave my answer :)

Comment: Ha ha . no a problem.  Give you an update Vote :)

Comment: @AmitBera How can I get customer group for each customer?

Comment: First you should get  customer load by` \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface` for getting customer group.You will get Customer group from there.

Comment: @AmitBera  I loaded customer groups as your answer above, now I need   to write a loop to get each customer's customer group. Can I edit above code to filter to load by customer Id or something?

Comment: @AmitBera,can we update group name by id?

Comment: yes,you can do that

Comment: @AmitBera, can you provide me with the line to update name by id? setGrouname not working

Comment: @AmitBera, Got is setCode() worked for me. Thanks

Comment: yes,it is right method

Answer (score 4):

Update your block:

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\GroupRepositoryInterface
 */
protected $groupRepository;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
 * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\GroupRepositoryInterface $groupRepository
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Customer\Api\GroupRepositoryInterface $groupRepository,
    array $data = []
) {
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
    $this->groupRepository = $groupRepository;
}

/**
 * @param $id
 * @return string
 */
public function getGroupNameById($id)
{
    $groupEntity = $this->groupRepository->getById($id);

    return $groupEntity->getCode();
}
```

use next code in the template:

```
<?php echo $block->getGroupNameById(1)?>
```

where the 1 is desired group id.

Answer (score 3):

You should not make such requests in template files. Use blocks for it.

Add `\Magento\Customer\Api\GroupRepositoryInterface $groupRepository` to the block.

And get group object like

```
/**
 * Customer group repository
 *
 * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\GroupRepositoryInterface
 */
protected $groupRepository;

public function __construct(
    // …
    \Magento\Customer\Api\GroupRepositoryInterface $groupRepository,
    // …
) {
    // …
    $this->groupRepository = $groupRepository;
    // …
}

public function getGroupCode($groupId) 
{
    $group = $this->groupRepository->getById($groupId);
    return $group->getCode();
}
```